# Inside list condition with jQuery

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, meta

I'm trying to build a jQuery function that triggers a specific event if the content of a `META` Tag is contained in a list of words.

I've tried:

```
<meta name="sun" content="a" >

<script>

$('meta[name=sun]').each(function(){
    var metacontent = $(this).attr("content");
    var list = ["a","b","c"];

if(metacontent.match(list)) { //that is wrong I guess
    console.log("hi");

}
});
</script>
```

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the jQuery utility function $.inArray

```
if($.inArray(metacontent, list) >= 0) {
.....
```

Comment: Heh, so it is and in fact it _really_ should be `if($.inArray(metacontent, list) >= 0) {` since the `a` is at index 0 and would cause the condition to evaluate to false without the comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkMeta(name, list) {
    var metacontent = $('meta[name="' + name + '"]').attr('content');

    return ($.inArray(metacontent, list) >= 0);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = ["a","b","c"];

    console.log(checkMeta('sun', list));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
<meta name="sun" content="a" >

<script>

$('meta[name="sun"]').each(function(){
    var metacontent = $(this).attr("content");
    var list = ["a","b","c"];

$.each(list, function(index, elem){
var matches = metacontent.match(/elem/g);

if(matches.length > 0){
  //it contains a list character
}else{
  //no list character found inside the metacontent
}
});

});
</script>
```